# An identity involving binomial coefficients and Stirling numbers of both kinds

Tags: combinatorics, summation, stirling-numbers

I calculated, using Mathematica, that for $4\leq k \leq 100$,
$$ \sum_{j=k}^{2k} \sum_{i=j+1-k}^j (-1)^j 2^{j-i} \binom{2k}{j} S(j,i) s(i,j+1-k) = 0,$$
where $s(i,j)$ and $S(i,j)$ are Stirling numbers of the first and second kinds, respectively.

Here the code:

> F[k_] := Sum[(-1)^j 2^(j - i) Binomial[2 k, j] StirlingS2[j, 
>        i] (StirlingS1[i, j + 1 - k]), {j, k, 2 k}, {i, j - k + 1, j}];
>
> Table[F[k], {k, 4, 100}]

How do I prove it holds for all $k \geq 4$ ?

Comment: are the $s(i,j)$ the signed or un-signed 1st kind numbers ?

Comment: @GCab, [signed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS1.html).

Comment: NB this seems to hold for $k \ge 1$, and the sum evaluates to $-1$ at $k=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks  like my first  response interprets the problem  statement to
use unsigned  Stirling numbers of the  first kind. We find  for signed
ones,

$$S_n = (-1)^{n+1} \sum_{j=n}^{2n} \sum_{k=j+1-n}^j
(-1)^k 2^{j-k} {2n\choose j} {j\brace k} 
{k\brack j+1-n}.$$

With the usual EGFs we get

$$(-1)^{n+1} \sum_{j=n}^{2n} \sum_{k=j+1-n}^j
(-1)^k 2^{j-k} {2n\choose j} j! [z^j] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
\\ \times k! [w^k] 
\frac{1}{(j+1-n)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1-n}.$$

Now we have

$${2n\choose j} j! \frac{1}{(j+1-n)!}
= \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-j)! \times (j+1-n)!}
= \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} {n+1\choose j+1-n}.$$

This yields for the sum

$$(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} 
\sum_{j=n}^{2n} {n+1\choose j+1-n} 2^j 
\\ \times [z^j] \sum_{k=j+1-n}^j (-1)^k 2^{-k} 
(\exp(z)-1)^k [w^k] 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1-n}
\\ = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} 2^n
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} 2^j 
\\ \times [z^{n+j}] \sum_{k=j+1}^{j+n} (-1)^k 2^{-k} 
(\exp(z)-1)^k [w^k] 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1}.$$

Observe that  $(\exp(z)-1)^k = z^k +  \cdots$ and hence we  may extend
the  inner  sum   beyond  $j+n$  due  to   the  coefficient  extractor
$[z^{n+j}].$ We find

$$(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!}  2^n
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} 2^j 
\\ \times [z^{n+j}] \sum_{k\ge j+1} (-1)^k 2^{-k} 
(\exp(z)-1)^k [w^k] 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1}.$$

Furthermore note that  $\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1} = w^{j+1}
+\cdots$ so that  the coefficient extractor $[w^k]$  covers the entire
series, producing

$$(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} 2^n
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} 2^j [z^{n+j}]
\left(\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}.$$

Working with formal power series we are justified in writing

$$[z^{n+j}] \left(\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}
= [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{z^{j+1}} 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}$$

because the logarithmic term  starts at $(-1)^{j+1} z^{j+1}/2^{j+1}.$
To see this write

$$-\frac{\exp(z)-1}{2} 
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^2}{2^2}
- \frac{1}{3} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^3}{2^3}
\pm \cdots$$

We continue

$$(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} 2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} 2^{j+1} 
\frac{1}{z^{j+1}} \left(\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}
\\ = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!}  2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {n+1\choose j} 2^{j} 
\frac{1}{z^{j}} \left(\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j}.$$

The term for $j=0$ in the sum is one and hence only contributes to
$n=1$ so that we may write

$$-[[n=1]] 
+ (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!}  2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{j=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose j} 2^{j} 
\frac{1}{z^{j}} \left(\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j}
\\ = -[[n=1]] 
+ (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!}  2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\left(1+\frac{2}{z} 
\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{n+1}.$$

Finally observe that

$$\left(1+\frac{2}{z} 
\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{n+1}
\\ = \left(1+\frac{2}{z} 
\left( -\frac{\exp(z)-1}{2} 
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^2}{2^2}
- \frac{1}{3} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^3}{2^3}
\pm \cdots \right)\right)^{n+1}
\\ = \left( -\frac{1}{4} z - \cdots \right)^{n+1}$$

and furthermore

$$[z^{n-1}] \left((-1)^{n+1} 
\frac{1}{4^{n+1}} z^{n+1} + \cdots \right) = 0$$

which is the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Just a first step (too long for a comment).

Let me change your symbology and put
$$
S(n) = \sum\limits_{j = n}^{2n} {\sum\limits_{k = j + 1 - n}^j {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} 2^{\,j - k} 
  \left( \matrix{2n \cr  j \cr}  \right)
 \left\{ \matrix{  j \cr   k \cr}  \right\}
\left[ \matrix{  k \cr j + 1 - n \cr}  \right]} }  
$$
where the brackets indicate  respectively the binomial, Stirling 2nd kind, un-signed Stirling 1st kind.

Note that if you extend the lower limit to start from $0$ then you get a cleaner result:
$S(n)=0$ for any $0 \le n$.
And since the sum bounds are implicit in the Binomial and Stirling numbers
we can plainly omit them, thus simplifying the algebraic operations.
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(n) = \sum\limits_{0\,\, \le \,j\, \le \,2n} {\;\sum\limits_{0\,\, \le \,k\, \le \,j} {
\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} 2^{\,j - k}
 \left( \matrix{  2n \cr   j \cr}  \right)\left\{ \matrix{  j \cr   k \cr}  \right\}\left[ \matrix{  k \cr   j + 1 - n \cr}  \right]}
 }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\,\, \le } \right)\,j\, \le \,\left( {2n} \right)} {\;\sum\limits_{\left( {0\,\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,j} \right)} {
\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} 2^{\,j - k}
 \left( \matrix{  2n \cr   j \cr}  \right)\left\{ \matrix{  j \cr   k \cr}  \right\}\left[ \matrix{  k \cr   j + 1 - n \cr}  \right]}
 } 
 = 0\quad \left| {\,0 \le n} \right. \cr
} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Working with the notation by @GCab we seek to evaluate

$$S_n = \sum_{j=n}^{2n} \sum_{k=j+1-n}^j
(-1)^j 2^{j-k} {2n\choose j} {j\brace k} 
{k\brack j+1-n}.$$

With the usual EGFs we get

$$\sum_{j=n}^{2n} \sum_{k=j+1-n}^j
(-1)^j 2^{j-k} {2n\choose j} j! [z^j] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
\\ \times k! [w^k] 
\frac{1}{(j+1-n)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1-n}.$$

Now we have

$${2n\choose j} j! \frac{1}{(j+1-n)!}
= \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-j)! \times (j+1-n)!}
= \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} {n+1\choose j+1-n}.$$

This yields for the sum

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} 
\sum_{j=n}^{2n} {n+1\choose j+1-n} (-1)^j 2^j 
\\ \times [z^j] \sum_{k=j+1-n}^j 2^{-k} 
(\exp(z)-1)^k [w^k] 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1-n}
\\ = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} (-1)^n 2^n
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} (-1)^j 2^j 
\\ \times [z^{n+j}] \sum_{k=j+1}^{j+n} 2^{-k} 
(\exp(z)-1)^k [w^k] 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1}.$$

Observe that  $(\exp(z)-1)^k = z^k +  \cdots$ and hence we  may extend
the  inner  sum   beyond  $j+n$  due  to   the  coefficient  extractor
$[z^{n+j}].$ We find

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} (-1)^n 2^n
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} (-1)^j 2^j
\\ \times  [z^{n+j}] \sum_{k\ge j+1} 2^{-k} 
(\exp(z)-1)^k [w^k] 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1}.$$

Furthermore note that  $\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^{j+1} = w^{j+1}
+\cdots$ so that  the coefficient extractor $[w^k]$  covers the entire
series, producing

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} (-1)^n 2^n
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} (-1)^j 2^j [z^{n+j}]
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}.$$

Working with formal power series we are justified in writing

$$[z^{n+j}] \left(\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}
= [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{z^{j+1}} 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}$$

because the logarithmic term starts  at $z^{j+1}/2^{j+1}.$ To see 
this write

$$\frac{\exp(z)-1}{2} 
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^2}{2^2}
+ \frac{1}{3} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^3}{2^3}
+ \cdots$$

We continue

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} (-1)^{n-1} 2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n+1\choose j+1} (-1)^{j+1} 2^{j+1} 
\frac{1}{z^{j+1}} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j+1}
\\ = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} (-1)^{n-1} 2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {n+1\choose j} (-1)^{j} 2^{j} 
\frac{1}{z^{j}} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j}.$$

The term for $j=0$ in the sum is one and hence only contributes to
$n=1$ so that we may write

$$-[[n=1]] 
+ \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} (-1)^{n-1} 2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{j=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose j} (-1)^{j} 2^{j} 
\frac{1}{z^{j}} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{j}
\\ = -[[n=1]] 
+ \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!} (-1)^{n-1} 2^{n-1} \\ \times [z^{n-1}]
\left(1-\frac{2}{z} 
\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{n+1}.$$

Finally observe that

$$\left(1-\frac{2}{z} 
\log\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)/2}\right)^{n+1}
\\ = \left(1-\frac{2}{z} 
\left( \frac{\exp(z)-1}{2} 
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^2}{2^2}
+ \frac{1}{3} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^3}{2^3}
+ \cdots \right)\right)^{n+1}
\\ = \left( -\frac{3}{4} z - \cdots \right)^{n+1}$$

and furthermore

$$[z^{n-1}] \left((-1)^{n+1} 
\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}} z^{n+1} + \cdots \right) = 0$$

which is the claim.